# Image slider wont center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to center my image slider, seems like an easy fix but I can't get it to center dead in the middle of my page (centered left & right, centered top and bottom) Any suggestions?
The image slider is `#logo-and-slider` in the CSS

Heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gZDVL/13/ (thanks to @MaggiQall)

And here is a live link to it: http://jtcraddock.ie/boards/

Comment: Can you set up an instance of this issue in jsfiddle / codepen? It would make it easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Heres the jsdiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gZDVL/ the div tags wont close in the image slider for some reaon so the images arent loading (they wont close only in jsfiddle) hope this helps you help me 
and heres a live link to it: http://jtcraddock.ie/boards/

Comment: @Dunne08 Properly close all img tags with <img/> syntax. <div> tags will close properly after that. Please help us by fixing the fiddle.

Comment: @Dunne08 I looked at the live link you posted. I don't understand what is the problem and what is the expected result. Please state your problem and expected result clearly.

Comment: @Dunne08, your example fiddle has a bunch of CSS in the javascript section, did you mean to copy paste different code in there?

Comment: @RaviH here is the fixed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gZDVL/13/ what my problem is, if you go to this link you will see my slider in action : jtcraddock.ie/boards i want to have it centered dead in the middle of the page, centered between left and right and centered between top and bottom,i cant seem to get it to center in my code

Comment: yeah sorry i meant to add js there, please look at my comment above to ravi to see what my problem is

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand.

Is this your desired result?

```
 <div><img src="http://testjd.net46.net/1.jpg" alt="1"/></div>

    <div><img src="http://testjd.net46.net/2.jpg" alt="1"/></div>

    <div><img src="http://testjd.net46.net/3.jpg" alt="1"/></div>
```

I closed your img-tags. with />

http://jsfiddle.net/gZDVL/2/

Comment: And I'd recommend adding `cursor:pointer;` to the `.controller`-class in your CSS

Comment: no, my problem is if you go to this link you will see my slider in action : jtcraddock.ie/boards i want to have it centered dead in the middle of the page, centered between left and right and centered between top and bottom,i cant seem to get it to center in my code. and thank your for the fixed jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure about whether you want to include the logo in the content to be centered. I have shown the idea below. I have added some borders to clearly display how the elements are laid out. If you don't want to include logo remove it from the HTML structure. Basically what I have done is placed the content in a table-cell element with the content center aligned horizontally with middle vertical alignment. That places the content at "dead center" as you wanted :-) See the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/linuxexpert/WYadL/

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="outer-box">
            <div class="inner-box">
                <div class="innermost-box">
                    <div class="logo">
                        Logo
                    </div>
                    <div class="controller">
                        <
                    </div>
                    <div class="scroller">
                        Image scroller
                    </div>
                    <div class="controller">
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.outer-box {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.inner-box {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}

.innermost-box {
    display:table;
    height:50%;
    width:80%;
    margin:0px auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.innermost-box > * {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.logo {
    width:40%;
}

.controller {
    width:5%;
}

.scroller {
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats exacly what I need thanks alot for this, I just needed to add a bit off CSS to the img to get them to respond, check my edit above. Out of curiosity, were you not able to make my original slider dead centered? this one: http://jtcraddock.ie/boards/

Comment: I cant seem to get this Swipe javascipt to work in the slider, do you think you could do it? https://github.com/thebird/Swipe